# MySQL Query - Getting distinct values

Tags: mysql

There is a table "T" that contains data as shown below:

```
A   B
---------
3    5   
4    6      
7    10 
8    5 
9    12 
3    6
3    7
8    7
```

Assuming a given input set of {3,8} as values for A, how to retrieve all distinct values of B for which all values in the input set has an entry?

```
B
---
5
7
```

EDIT: I think the question is not clear enough. I want values in B which have a record with all values in the given set as a value for column A. So, B=6 will not be included since there is no record with A=8 and B=6. Hope this makes it clear!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT B 
FROM my_table WHERE A IN (3,8)
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT B FROM AB WHERE A = 3
INTERSECT
SELECT B FROM AB WHERE A = 8
```

INTERSECT give you the rows which occurs in both resultsets.

2nd EDIT:

```
SELECT B,COUNT(B) 
FROM AB WHERE A IN (3,8) 
GROUP BY B 
HAVING COUNT(B) = 2
```

You should however modify this in two places: in IN arguments and on the end, in COUNT(B) = ?. ? should be equal the number of the arguments. I hope this will help.

3rd EDIT:

```
SELECT B,COUNT(B) 
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT A, B FROM AB
) x
WHERE A IN (3,8) 
GROUP BY B 
HAVING COUNT(B) = 2
```

This will avoid the duplicate entries problem.

Comment: +1: Short and sweet. The "IN" operator solves many many problems: though the WHERE clause could also be written as "WHERE (A = '3' OR A = '8')", using IN is clearly more readable and concise.

Comment: But MySQL does not support intersects :(

Comment: Even assuming that intersect is available, this method will become unwieldy if the input set has too many values in it.

Comment: Another solution. Much better I think.

Comment: I think this solution doesn't work if duplicated rows are allowed in this table.  In other words, if the row {A:3, B:7} were to appear twice, this query would return {7,2}, which is wrong.

Comment: Check my 3rd edit. You can first select distinct values and the use my query.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can create two subqueries where you filter out only the rows that are candidates for matching (i.e. A is either 3 or 8).  Then join those rows with each other on the value of B, and any matching rows will be what you're looking for.  I'm not 100% certain of the syntax for MySQL, but I believe this will work:

`SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT * FROM T WHERE A = 3) t3 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM T WHERE A = 8) t8 ON t3.B = t8.B`